row_spec create an empty line in markdown latex
Iam running a pdf in markdown
The viewer in Rstudio show the right table but when i render, the table looks like this
`
tabla <- data.frame(Suceso=c("H","M","Total"),
                    Rosa=c(0.3,0.2,0.5),Azul=c(0.18,0.12,0.3),Verde=c(0.12,0.08,0.2), Total=c(0.6,0.4,1),check.names = F)

kable(tabla,align=c("l","c","c"),escape=F,booktabs=T,linesep="",digits = 2)%>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options=c("striped","borderer","condensed"), 
                latex_options = "HOLD_position",full_width = F,font_size = 10)%>%
  column_spec(c(1,4),border_right = T)%>%
  row_spec(2, hline_after = TRUE)

`
Output with empty row in the end

I am having the same issue! Have not found a solution.
